# Different Date.ToString (IE 8 local site vs google)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, datetime

So what I am doing is typing into the dev console this line of javascript `new aDate = new Date().toString()`. When I am on google.com it returns me this `Mon Mar 7 17:50:15 PST 2016`, but when I go to my local site and do the same thing I get the UTC format `Mon Mar 07 2016 17:50:52 GMT-0800` I need the value in local time like what I see when I am on google.com. Is anyone aware of this issue before? I am only getting this in IE 8 and 9, but 11 is ok. I think this happens after someone added the ECMAScript 5, which I believe maybe changing the javascript date time object. I know that Micorosoft stopped supporting anything lower then 11, but we still need to support 8 and 9 until our customers are done migrating. Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "on Google"? Do you mean Chrome?

Comment: @Pointy I meant when I navigate to google.com and then in the dev console the toString prints out the local time, but when I got to my site localsite.com and do the same thing I get a UTC date.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense unless code in your own page(s) overrides `Date.prototype.toString()`. What exactly does "someone added the ECMAScript 5" mean? You can't "add" ES5 to a site; a browser either supports ES5 or it doesn't (and IE8 and 9 both support at least most of ES5 anyway).

Comment: @Pointy The other day I was looking at some changes checked in and there was these es5shim.js and es5Sham.js checked. I asked about it and he said it had to do with ecmaScript5 support. That what i was thinking too that something (the shim and sham) is overriding the `Date.prototype.toString()`

Comment: From the console you can type `Date.prototype.toString` to check, or just look in those source files. Without seeing any of the code involved, it's hard to say.

Comment: @Pointy So I checked the source and it seems that es5Shim does have a block of code that overrides `Date.prototype.toString`. So I commented that out and still have the wrong formatting. Currently looking in other areas to see if it is being overridden somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display same time format regardless of browser, try using Moment.js (  http://momentjs.com )